# Serialization , compilation and byte code generation

Tags: java, serialization, compilation

I have the following class hierarchy

```
  ParentInterface

        |
        v
    ParentClass

       /    \ 
      v      v 

  SubClass1   SubClass2
```

The interface does not extend `Serializable` interface and none of the classes implement `Serializable` interface as well. All the classes were compiled and packaged into a jar file.

Now, i change the `ParentInterface` so that it extends `Serializable` interface. After this, i only replace the `ParentInterface.class` file in the jar.

I have some code where I am trying to Serialize an instance of `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`. When trying to serialize, i get `NotSerializableException`.

I assume, if i had compiled all the classes again and replaced them in my jar, it would have worked. Whats wrong if i replace only the `ParentInterface`?

Comment: Don't assume it would work on a recompile - try it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

> All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.

According to JavaDoc, the SubClass1 and SubClass2 should be serializable.. unless they have some *fields*, that are not serializable.

Double check the serializablity of the fields inside `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`.

Answer (score 1):

This may help..

*SubClass1* and *SubClass2* will by definition be serializable

However as advised pay particular attention to fields contained in both *SubClass1* and *SubClass2*. Paying attention to the below restriction described in the JDK.

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream.

Be sure to make "un-serialisable" fields as *transient* or act as appropriate.